# Pandas dateoffset giving wrong offset month

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, data-science

I am trying to offset a date by 1 month from the following code

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from pandas.tseries.offsets import DateOffset
ts = pd.to_datetime('2017-03-30')
ts=ts + DateOffset(months=1)
ts.date()
```

the answer comes out to be `datetime.date(2017, 4, 30)`

and for the

```
ts = pd.to_datetime('2017-03-31')
ts=ts + DateOffset(months=1)
ts.date()
```

the answer is same `datetime.date(2017, 4, 30)`
why is this happening ? I am trying to offset one month date for `pd.date_range('2022-03-27',end='2022-06-04',freq='D')`

Comment: As April 31 is not a valid date, it will return April 30. What did you expect as a result? May 1? `DateOffset(months=1)` is not adding a certain amount of days to your time-stamp, but is adding 1 month to your time-stamp such that it is still a valid date

Comment: @TobiasMolenaar  I want May 1 . How to do that?

Comment: Well, you can use `DateOffset(days=31`